# Visual studio 2010 - crashing on VPN network change... any ideas?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, vpn

Many times when I change VPN status by disconnecting a remote network my VS instance immediately crashes.

This is the closest thing I can find in the event log.  Anyone have any ideas about this?

`Exception: System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException`

`Message: Invalid access to memory location`

`StackTrace:    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemNetworkInterface.GetAdaptersAddresses(AddressFamily family, FixedInfo fixedInfo)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemNetworkInterface.PostWin2KGetNetworkInterfaces(AddressFamily family)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemNetworkInterface.GetNetworkInterfaces(AddressFamily family)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemNetworkInterface.InternalGetIsNetworkAvailable()
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.AvailabilityChangeListener.ChangedAddress(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.AddressChangeListener.AddressChangedCallback(Object stateObject, Boolean signaled)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(Object state, Boolean timedOut)`

Comment: Similar problem here, and also, FYI, it happens to me when I undock my laptop.

Comment: Are you using Team Foundation? There is a mechanism where you can configure an Instant Messenger client to relay build notifications and other stuff. (This is under Team Explorer, somewhere related to Team Members - I can dig out the details when I am back to work on Monday). 

Anyway, we have seen an issue where VS2010 dies when it cannot start the IM client. This sounds vaguely similar.

Comment: Oh, and does that happen only when getting off the VPN, or when you get on as well? Sounds like a service that it needs is no longer available, and that's when it dies. Maybe you could check with Process Explorer what kind of TCP connections it has open, maybe that will give you some new ideas.

Comment: The stack trace I've seen shows a network status change event. Happens on VPN change, disconnecting from wifi, waking after sleep. I had it happen with a solution that had never been in TFS.

Answer (score 1):

I got this exception when running my 32 bit application (which was built with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE enabled) on Windows 7 from time to time. While trying to find the problem I came across a hotfix that appears to fix the issue.

Try the following hotfix and see if that fixes it for you: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2588507